# Emacs: how do I add at the ends of the line

Tags: emacs

I'm talking about `query-replace-regexp`. To add at the beginning of the line if `vi` I can do:

```
:%s/^/myBeginning
```

To add to the end of each line in `vi` one can do:

```
:%s/$/myEnd
```

Direct analogues don't work in `emacs`: `^` and `$` with no additional chars do not match anything. It is most easily seen in `re-builder`. If You'll replace `^` by `myBeginning` - nothing changes. So my question is - how can it be done in `Emacs` - how can one add a word to the beginning/end of the lines?

**Edit**:

Of cource it works if I do:

```
Find   : ^\(.*\)
Replace: myBeginning\1

Find   : \(.*\)$
Replace: \1myEnd
```

My point is that in `vi` -  I dont' have to write: `\(.*\)`. It works fine just with `$` as a find string or `^` at the beginning. So I was wondering - if it can be done as easily in Emacs.

P.S. `emacs -Q` gives the same behavior.

**Edit 2**:

Oh my God - it works! It hightlights nothing, and I forgot to press `!` finally.

Comment: So what are you using? `C-M-% $ myEnd`? `C-M-% (.*)$ \1myEnd`?

Comment: You're still not giving a recipe.  What you say does not work does for me.  I'm able to replace `^` with a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can do it with `emacs -Q` <kbd>C-M-%</kbd> or <kbd>M-x</kbd> `query-replace-regexp`.  Works as expected.  Can you give a recipe for how this doesn't work for you starting with `emacs -Q`?